# Hydrogen Bonding in case of nitro group

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrogen-bond

[image: I have taken nitrophenol just for reference]In many different cases of Nitro group I have seen that only one oxygen atom is particularly used for hydrogen bonding but not the other one.But I guess both the bonds should be polar and hence show hydrogen bonding.

Please explain.

Comment: I have just used nitro phenol for reference.

Comment: Yes, both N-O bonds are equivalent, so either can form hydrogen-bonds. However, both oxygens forming hydrogen bonds at the same time is probably unlikely due to geometry constraints.

Answer (score 4):

The oxygen atoms are indistinguishable. That they look distinct is an artifact of the Lewis notation. There are examples when both are acting as hydrogen bond acceptor.